# Angular Js controller not firing with routes

Tags: angularjs

I am having a problem with AngularJS, where suddenly one of my controllers refuse to execure.

I load it with route, and i know the route is loaded as the html page attached is requested and inserted into the ng-view div i have.

My routes

```
  when('/products/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/products/products.html',
    controller: 'productsController'
  }).      
  when('/products/:productId', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/products/product.html',
    controller: 'productController'
  }).
```

I did not see any problems in my controller so i tried replacing all content with just a simple console log, and yet it do still not execute.

```
angular.module('DietPlanApp').controller('productsController',
    ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log('Get my products!');
}]);
```

My other controller productController workes just fine.

```
angular.module('DietPlanApp').controller('productController', 
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'productService', 'userService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, productService, userService) {

    productService.getProduct(userService.getUserToken(), $routeParams.productId, function (data) {
        if(data.result) {
            $scope.product = transferToPortionSize(data.product);
        } else {
            $location.path("/products/");
        }
    });

    $scope.save = function () {
        productService.save(userService.getUserToken(), transferToUnitSize($scope.product));
        $location.path("/products/");
    };
    $scope.delete = function () {
        productService.deleteProduct(userService.getUserToken(), $scope.product.id);
        $location.path("/products/");
    };
}]);
```

And i have verified that the js files for productsController is loaded correctly in the HTML head, in the same way productController is.

[image]

Comment: try to reproduce it on http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: I need more information. Can you create plunker of your code ?

Comment: https://github.com/KRSogaard/DietPlanner/tree/master/public
I will work on uploading it to plunker

Comment: Got a running example here http://64.46.24.119:3000/#/products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the result of a namespace collision. You are overwriting `productsController` in `public/app/components/users/authController.js`.

It was probably the result of a copy/paste that your forgot to rename. That seems like the most likely culprit.

See the screenshot [here](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAWn-GzPE79JubKR6hvkUJqkItKZ1KZKzZE).

Comment: Thanks, can not believe i overlooked that :D Had a suspension it was something like that :D

Comment: I've been guilty of this once or twice :)